# While loop does not work, it reads the first line and exits and the locate command that is used does not output the value

Tags: scripts, find

We have a shell script which should read line from a file, where the file contents are the filenames, we need to locate the path of these filenames and copy to a different directory.
Here we have written the below shell script, each time the script behaves differently
At once the while loop just reads one line and exits
At second instance, the locate command works fine for first line of the file and the second line in the file does not provide the output it gives a blank output

## Shell Script

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
file="test.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    # display $line or do somthing with $line
        echo "$line"
        fileloc=`locate "$line"`        
        i=`echo $?`
    if [ $? != 0 ]
    then
        echo "Unsuccessful" 
    else              
        echo $fileloc 
        cp $fileloc /home/user/PO_AUDIT
        echo "Successful"  
    fi     
done <"$file"
```

test.txt
(below are the filenames that are stored in our server)

```
11687892
11687893
```

Comment: You probably **don't** want `i=`echo $?`` between the `locate` command and the `if [ $? != 0 ]` test - you will end up testing the exit status of the `echo`

Answer (score 0):

why IHS= at this place?

If IFS is needed for thos script, you might consider something like

```
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=
... your script
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

The beginning of yout script this becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
file="test.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
```